# Azure Api Management - set favicon on developer portal, edit greetings email template

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

Could you help me with two very simple and obvious question:

1. How to set a favicon on developer portal in azure api management?
2. How to edit an email template for a newly created user account? In notifications tab there are any other template except this one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the favico using this script.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/content/MediaLibrary/CustomAssets/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not support setting your own favicon. It's on our radar though.

Regarding your second question, we do not send notification when new users sign up. Is that something you need? Feel free to raise a request in our uservoice http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management

Comment: Hi Miao, thanks for your reponse. I saw link you posted, thanks. But the question is different. When user signed up, he received the following emai:

Subject:
Please confirm your new [api name] account

Body: 
Dear xxx,
Thank you for joining the [api name] program! We host a growing number of cool APIs and strive to provide an awesome experience for API developers.  ...

And I see no possibility to change this template from 'Notifications' section. Could you please tell me if I can do this? Or what's wrong here.

Comment: Hi, currently the signup confirmation is not customizable. Can you please raise a request in our UserVoice http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management I'll see if we can get it done in the near future. Thanks.

Comment: @MiaoJiang any update here? As you know the missing favicon.ico causes our sign in scenario with AAD to get a 404 and thus potentially loop back to the sign in screen.